# Get data back into webpage after AJAX call and serialport message.

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, linux, express

New to JavaScript and Node.js

I have a setup where I have a raspberry pi running Node.js. The raspberry pi is connected to some embedded device through a USB to UART connection with the USB plugged into the raspberry pi. I can send and receive data at this base level just fine. The pi is connected to a router and I access it through it's IP and a browser.

I want to host a simple webpage that has a title, some text, and a button. When I click the button I want my client machine to contact the node.js server and make the pi send a message(already have a message format I am required to use) over the serial port to the embedded device. I want to wait/or not(depends on suggestions) for data to be sent back and then use that data to repopulate the text on the webpage.

What I have is close to this but not complete.

I run a 'server' on node.js off the pi. It uses express and a static page. The static page has a client side JavaScript file that executes a AJAX request when the button is clicked. On the node.js side I have express able to see the AJAX request. I then construct and send my message over serial port to the embedded device using [serialport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport). At this point, on the Node.js side I can send back a string of text/etc. that can be displayed by the webpage but don't know how to somehow wait or other wise receive the data and send it to the webpage for displaying.

Client .html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Request Sensor Data</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
          <p>Sensor Data</p>
          <p><TEXTAREA id="myTxtArea" NAME="sensorDataTxtBox" ROWS=3 COLS=30 ></TEXTAREA></br>
             <button type="button" name="sensorButton" id="mySensorButton" onClick="getSensorData()" >Get Sensor Data</button></p>
    <script src="clientCode.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Client .js:

```
function getSensorData()
{
    console.log('getSensorData() button pushed.');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'sensorGET');
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
      var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
      if (xhr.readyState === DONE) 
      {
        if (xhr.status === OK)
        {
          //insert DOM grabs to set text in html textbox. 
          console.log(xhr.responseText); // 'This is the returned text.'
          var textAreaDOM = document.getElementById('myTxtArea');
          textAreaDOM.value = textAreaDOM.value + 'inserted sensor data here\n';
        } 
        else 
        {
          console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
        }
      }
    };
}
```

node.js .js:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(); 
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/sensorGET', function (req, res) {
   var sensorData = getSensorData(); 
   res.send('sensorData');
})


var serialport = require('serialport'),
portname = '/dev/ttyUSB0';

var myPort = new serialport(portname, {
    baudRate: 115200,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1, 
    flowControl: false,
    parser: serialport.parsers.byteLength(1) 
});

myPort.on('open', showPortOpen);
myPort.on('data', recSerialData);
myPort.on('close', showPortClosed);
myPort.on('error', showError);
myPort.on('disconnect', showDisconnect);


function showDisconnect() {
    console.log('Someone disconnected');
}
function showPortOpen()
{
    console.log('port open. Data rate: ' + myPort.options.baudRate);
}   
function recSerialData(data)
{
    parseMessage(data);//This function is not shown but parses a message that is sent on the wire
}
function showPortClosed()
{
    console.log('port closed.');
}
function showError(error)
{
    console.log('Serial port error: ' + error);
}


function getSensorData()
{
    myPort.write(Assume correct message is sent here);
    //Can return some set text here and it will be written to the webpage. 
    //example: return "Temp data was asked for...";
    //is there a way to wait here for the next message that comes in?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest thing will actually be to use something like socket.io and just send the data to the browser with that after every parseMessage.  Because for starters if you try to make http wait for all serial data it will likely timeout, and the way things work its just easier to send every time you get a new data event from the serial port.